# Rotation of a moving 2d plot in Octave/Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have to create a program which simulates a vacuum cleaner robot. We have to do it with Octave.

```
Main()
  clear all;

  %Initalisierung der Raummatrix, damit nachher abgefragt werden kann
  XMatrix = 0;
  YMatrix = 0;

  %"Winkel festsetzten"
  t=1;
  h=1;
  hold on
  %Startpunkte vom Punkt
  x = 20;
  y = 15;
  alpha = 45; 

  xalt= 10;
  yalt= 10;

  %Hier die Methode ändern um verschiedene Räume einzulesen
  [XMatrix,YMatrix] = RaummitsechsEcken();

  %plot Funktion wird gespeichert
  p =  plot(x,y,'*');
  %p1 = plot(x,y,xalt,yalt);

 while(true)


  pause(0.001) 

  %alte Position speichern
  xalt = get(p,'XData');
  yalt = get(p,'YData');

  %Bewegungsberechnung
  set(p,'YData',get(p,'YData')+0.1*t);
  set(p,'XData',get(p,'XData')+0.1*h);

  % Strich plot

    %Kollisionabfrage
    if(inpolygon(get(p,'XData'),get(p,'YData'),XMatrix,YMatrix) == false)

      %Alte Position zurückspielen    
      set(p,'XData',xalt);
      set(p,'YData',yalt);

      %Neue Winkelberechnung(random)
     t =  -1+rand(1)*(1-(-1));
      h =  -1+rand(1)*(1-(-1));


    endif

  endwhile

endfunction


function[X,Y] = RaummitsechsEcken()

X = [10 18 10 30 22 30 10];
Y = [1 16 30 30 16 1 1];

plot(X,Y)
hold on
endfunction
```

The problem with the code is when the "robot" hits the wall, that he is randomly generate a new angel and moves now in this way. The problem is here that the robot has the same variable for the angle and the speed. So the speed varies with the angle. My question is now if someone knows how to move my point on the same speed but change the direction apart from the speed when the robot hits the wall. I have searched for a rotationmatrix but I can not make it work with that. 
I hope you can help!

Felix

Comment: Use two variables?

Comment: Or normalize `t` and `h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is little bit tricky. As you are setting new location of robot in cartesian coordinates system, the angle and speed are always going to change simultaneously because x and y coordinates control both parameters. But there is very simple solution, if you use convert cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates you will get angle and magnitude. Replace the magnitude with a constant speed factor and calculate the h and t values again i.e. cartesian coordinates. So you just need to add these ***three*** lines in your code.

```
angle = atan2(t,h);
t = speedFactor*sin(angle);
h = speedFactor*cos(angle);
```

**Your code will look like:**

```
Main()
  clear all;


  % You can control speed by increasing or decreasing this parameter.
  speedFactor = 0.1;


  %Initalisierung der Raummatrix, damit nachher abgefragt werden kann
  XMatrix = 0;
  YMatrix = 0;

  %"Winkel festsetzten"
  t=1;
  h=1;



  hold on
  %Startpunkte vom Punkt
  x = 20;
  y = 15;
  alpha = 45; 

  xalt= 10;
  yalt= 10;

  %Hier die Methode ändern um verschiedene Räume einzulesen
  [XMatrix,YMatrix] = RaummitsechsEcken();

  %plot Funktion wird gespeichert
  p =  plot(x,y,'*');
  %p1 = plot(x,y,xalt,yalt);

 while(true)


  pause(0.001) 

  %alte Position speichern
  xalt = get(p,'XData');
  yalt = get(p,'YData');

  %Bewegungsberechnung
  set(p,'YData',get(p,'YData')+0.1*t);
  set(p,'XData',get(p,'XData')+0.1*h);

  % Strich plot

    %Kollisionabfrage
    if(inpolygon(get(p,'XData'),get(p,'YData'),XMatrix,YMatrix) == false)

      %Alte Position zurückspielen    
      set(p,'XData',xalt);
      set(p,'YData',yalt);

      %Neue Winkelberechnung(random)
       t =  -1+rand(1)*(1-(-1));
      h =  -1+rand(1)*(1-(-1));

      angle = atan2(t,h);
      t = speedFactor*sin(angle);
      h = speedFactor*cos(angle);


    endif

  endwhile

endfunction


function[X,Y] = RaummitsechsEcken()

X = [10 18 10 30 22 30 10];
Y = [1 16 30 30 16 1 1];

plot(X,Y)
hold on
endfunction
```

Comment: This works wonderful! I will try to unterstand everything, but the first test works fine! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Felix Please don't hesitate to vote my answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: I did, but my votes will not be showed, because my reputation is to low...I can only mark as the "best" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Beside using just the angle, you should also set the axis to "equal" to get the correct visual impression of velocity.

```
p =  plot (x, y, '*');
axis ("equal");
```

and in the calculation pf the new position

```
set(p,'YData',get(p,'YData')+0.2*sin(alpha));
set(p,'XData',get(p,'XData')+0.2*cos(alpha));
```

After collision

```
alpha = 2*pi*rand ();
```

which gives (I also modified your room to make it more interesting)

[image]

Comment: The axis("equal") is a good thing, thank you for that. Beside that we have created a lot of rooms before we did this programm. One thing I dont understand is, you calcute a angle randomly in a another way like we did it, right?

Comment: Yes, I assume the vehicle uses a constant velocity (0.2 units per timestep in the above example) and just the angle in which the vehicle drives changes after collission randomly between 0 and 2*pi (0 and 360°). Btw, which kind of school do you learn Octave? Realschule, Gymnasium?

Comment: So, all in all you calculate it in a polar system and we calculate it in a cartesian system. I learn it at a university for two different subjects. Mathematics and signals and systems.